# How can I solve this WCF problem?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

There is a WCF program(I will call this as "ABC").
This WCF program("ABC") can host a service or connect to the service that hosted other "ABC". So, "ABC" can be host program or client program.
First "ABC" discover that any service that hosted, if find, connect to the service.
or host the service.

If a "ABC" start, and then theother "ABC" start, "ABC" that start first will be host, and "ABC" that start after will be client.

In this point I have a question.
If two "ABC" start in same time, The two "ABC" fail to find a hosted service all, and host respectively each. I want solve this.
Although two "ABC" start simultaneously, the first should be host, and the second should be client. How can I this? Any other good algorithm ?

Comment: This seems quite weird... an app that is once a server, once a client... depending on when it gets started... odd ... what are you trying to do, ultimately??

Comment: I want to implement wcf program about discovery and Ad-hoc. So, I need to do this situation.

Comment: Still - seems very odd that a single app should be once a service, once a client. Also: suppose suddenly two instances of "ABC" discover they're both servers - how do you know/decide which one needs to "morph" into a client?? How do you make sure not both get converted?? Seems odd.....

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have a central location that tracks whether or not a host instance is running. Have each instance call it and say they want to be a host instance, and let it return a value indicating whether there is a host instance already running or not (or put another way, an indication of whether the caller *should* be a host instance). Have each instance enter the appropriate mode based on the reply. Let the server track the state and wait until the running host instance crashes, then you can watch the fireworks...

Comment: Thanks your reply. but I want to solve this problem without any server or central location. only each other same "ABC"s should solve this situations.